# Spring Integration: Obtaining logs and handling callbacks from the default MQTT Paho client

Tags: spring, spring-integration, mqtt

Below is an interesting example of sending messages over MQTT with the standard outbound-channel-adapter (not the MQTT outbound adapter):
https://github.com/joshlong/spring-integration-mqtt

The authors implement their own message handler, and pass it to the adapter.

Now my question is: Is it possible to implement a custom message handler using the MQTT outbound adapter? Or is it only possible with the general outbound-channel-adapter of Spring Integration?

My objective is to obtain logs and handle callbacks from the Paho client, so I can for example handle connection errors, timeouts, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Spring Integration 4.0 provides the MQTT module with `MqttPahoMessageHandler` as default implementation of `AbstractMqttMessageHandler`.

I'd say that you can extend from `MqttPahoMessageHandler` to achieve your `MqttCallback` wishes, but yes, you can use that custom `MessageHandler` implementation only from `<int:outbound-channel-adapter ref="">`.

The out-of-the-box `<int-mqtt:outbound-channel-adapter>` is just for population a bean for `MqttPahoMessageHandler` and you can't change that behaviour.

From other side, when you will start to do Spring Integration from JavaConfig you will get deal just only with classes, so there is no boundaries to restict you with custom tags:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sendToMqttChannel")
@Bean
public MessageHandler mqttHandler() {
   return new MyMqttPahoMessageHandler();
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide any recent source code about implementing a custom MqttPahoMessageHandler? The example I referenced is too old now. Also, can you please be more specific about your last suggestion (JavaConfig, ServiceActivator, etc...)

Comment: Actually just see the source code for the Spring Integration 4.0 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-mqtt/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mqtt/outbound). as well as its Reference Manual - http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/whats-new.html#4.0-bean-messaging-annotations